# JS -Jquery - call a method from inside a Jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, accordion

I have a pretty functional accordion from a 3rd party script I found on one of the my old archived websites (hence not my own coding ).

http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/Rm8Py/1/

Now , I am not a Javascript person , And I would like to know how to make a global toggle button that will open / close the whole set at one click, calling the methods from inside the script is possible ..
I tried to do

```
jQuery(this).accordion().activate(this, 'toggle', 'parents');
```

and also just

```
jQuery('ul').accordion().activate();
```

But since my JS skills are close to NULL , I can not seems to make that work ..

Is there a way to call some Inside method from within this function that will be a global toggle trigger to all the levels and accordions , without having to change the plugin code itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand; the whole point of an accordion is that only one pane is open at a time, and the toggle code enforces that. It's not too hard to modify that plugin to call its `activate` helper function on all the ULs, but as it opens each pane, it will close all the other panes, thereby stomping on itself.

Also, you don't want to toggle all the panes, because some are closed and some are open, so toggling each one won't accomplish getting them globally open or closed.

Instead, you'll have to manipulate the DOM directly, bypassing the accordion's logic. This will open all of the panes when you click the "toggle" link:

```
jQuery("#toggle").click(function(){$("ul").slideDown()});
```

To actually make it toggle, try this instead:

```
(function(){
    var isClosed = true;
    jQuery("#toggle").click(function(){
        if (isClosed) {
            jQuery("ul").slideDown();
        }
        else {
             jQuery("ul").find("ul").slideUp();
        }
        isClosed = !isClosed;
    });
})();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rm8Py/2/

Comment: Thanks ! while both answered work, and actually @Matt 's answer was more directly to my original question, your answer had a logic that is correct (I did wanted something of a "global open and close all" rather than toggle . thanks .

Answer (score 1):

`activate` effectively is a private function, you can't call it from outside the plugin without changing the plugin code.

To expose it it's common to accept method names as arguments. (Code simplified, normally a bit more elegant.)

```
accordion: function(method, arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (method == "activate") {
            activate(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        }
       // ....
    })
```

You can now call it like this:

```
 myAccordion.accordion("activate", $("ul"))
```

The plugin code is minified (single-character variable names), so I'm not sure what parameters the `activate` function expects.

Comment: That exposes `activate`, but it's not really clear that will do what the OP wants, since `activate` opens one UL and closes its sibling ULs.

Comment: @IsaacCambron Good point. I'll leave it here though since it answers how to call a method that's inside a jQuery plugin. You're right though, using non-plugin Javascript code is probably better to achieve the goal.

Comment: thanks , this is what I wanted as means of how to call external function, (+1) though in the end, to simplify my code I did used @Isaac Cambron method. more noob friendly.